# Help in manually adding Windows 8.1 to grub loader

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, grub2, windows-8, bootloader

I have just repaired my boot loader using the instructions in this video - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i97y5Y2nChs

Although it can detect Linux Ubuntu, it can't detect my Windows 8.1. The Youtube video shows us how to remove an entry from the grub loader from grub.cfg, but didn't showed us how to add one. Any help will be appreciated.

http://paste.ubuntu.com/14602238/

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

There is no Ubuntu operating system shown in the pastebin output.
There also is no Windows operating system in the pastebin output.
Just guessing - did you install Ubuntu using the Wubi application ?

Rebuild the BCD store and install Ubuntu the recommended way.
This is a slightly chance to getting your problem - partly - solved.
Otherwise you have to reinstall Windows and after that Ubuntu.

Boot from the Windows (DVD/USB) installation media.
On Install now screen choose Repair your computer.
In the Recovery Options select Command Prompt.

Execute the following commands:

```
bootrec.exe /fixboot  
bootrec.exe /rebuildbcd
```

Boot from the Ubuntu (DVD/USB) installation media.
Select Try Ubuntu without installing, on the desktop,
Open GParted, generate sufficient space for Ubuntu.
Delete unnecessary partitions - only you know which.
Close GParted and now start the Ubuntu installation.

Comment: Yes, I have done the grub boot repair from the trial Linux Ubuntu. I have not installed Linux Ubuntu yet. I have a pre-installed genuine Windows 8.1 on my laptop.

Comment: I have repaired my grub loader through 'Try Linux Ubuntu', as exactly shown in the Youtube video.

Comment: @JordanSharma : When you don't have Ubuntu or any other Linux distribution installed, you cannot install or repair the GRUB boot loader - so you have to install Ubuntu - afterwards you can boot the systems from GRUB. :)